# python np.append: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3-dimensional array called M_new and I want to create a new 2-dimensional array called M_final by appending each pages of M_new (M_new has in total 152 pages), so I write the following for-loop:

```
for i in np.linspace(0,152,77):
    M_final=np.append(M_new[i,:,:],M_new[i+1,:,:],axis=0)
```

and then a index error was raised:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

where I did wrong? or maybe there's another way to extent the 3-dimensional array to a 2-dimensional one?

Comment: How about `M_new.reshape(-1,M_new.shape[-1])`?

Comment: I just tries this but it turns out M_new is still a 3-dimensional array

Comment: Where does the 77 come from? `np.linspace(0, 152, 77)` produces an array of 77 float values uniformly distributed between 0 and 152; you can not use such values to index another array.

Comment: Assign it back : `M_new = M_new.reshape(-1,M_new.shape[-1])`?

Comment: I want to create a number list like 0,2,4,6......so the number of the elements in the list will be (152-0/2)+1=77, to make sure that all pages can be appended into M_final

Comment: yes assign it back will change the shape immortally. of cause it has to be assigned back.... thx :)

Comment: and why shape[-1] returns the number of columns?